# Kendo datepicker: distinguishing null from invalid value

Tags: jquery, mvvm, kendo-ui, datepicker

My jQuery MVVM form has several optional Kendo Datepickers for which I'm having trouble implementing a business rule in the validation: namely, that a null value is acceptable, but an invalid date (such as 2/30/2018) must be rejected.

Kendo equates these two values, such that 2/30/2018 is treated as a null value, and also undefined. Also, the null value returns true for (== undefined AND === undefined), so I can't discern between null and undefined in either direction.

Is there a way to evaluate the value or innerHTML or textbox part of the Datepicker, distinguishing "true" null and any non-null value, even if invalid?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [validator](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/validator/overview) to verify that the entered dates are valid.
https://dojo.telerik.com/@SiliconSoul/avODUPoT

Comment: The problem I'm having is that the empty datepicker is evaluating to undefined. Even an === undefined comparison evaluates true for null value in the datepicker.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you mean but I don't think that you should rely on null or undefined to check if the value is not entered or invalid. If you can't use the validator then I can suggest to try with a custom value binding that sets specific value for invalid values: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/bindings/custom

Comment: The example does not use a kendo datepicker. It also does not distinguish from a null value and an invalid date.